# Android Get Data from web

Tags: android, networking

I tried to read the content in a text file on the remote server through my Android phone. The URL of the file is `192.168.43.157:8080/apk/list.txt`, and I have tested that the server works well, by using my browser on PC and pasted the URL in the address bar.

I have added uses-permissions:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    ...
```

And this is the code in Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    String listUrl = "http://192.168.43.157:8080/apk/list.txt";

    String response = getWebResponse(listUrl);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web_response);
    textView.setText(response);

}

private String getWebResponse(String urlStr) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        } 
        return response.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

I have tried to use `HttpURLConnection` and `URLConnection`, neither of them would work. And I have use the debug to check the code. The program failed at

```
private String getWebResponse(String urlStr) {
    ...
    InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
    ....
}
```

`httpConn.getInputStream()` keeps returning `null`.

Please help me to get off the hook here!

Comment: `The url of the file is: "192.168.43.157:8080/apk/list.txt"`. No. That is nu url. The url is `http://192.168.43.157:8080/apk/list.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. But If I get rid of "http:" .  The program raises exception on " URL url = new URL(urlStr);".  The original raise exception on "InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();"

Comment: Who told you to get rid of http://?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use some libraries which make it easy 
for example using [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library ( by google )

the example :

```
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
       // get the response 
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       // error msg
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

---

and by the way , if you are using emulator , you should put this ip adress`10.0.2.2`

Comment: The fact is I am in a damed country who has blocked google. I do not have the package volley installed.

Answer (score 1):

this code works for me.

```
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

       urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                //InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: It seems the difference between our code is that you called the method: "urlConnection.connect()".  I have tried it , the program still raised an exception on  "InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();"

Comment: what is the content of the list.txt?

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, you just cannot use main thread to get content from web, and I have to do it use "AsyncTask". Although I do not understand why it should be, but after I wrap the process within an AsyncTask class, the program works. I have met the same problem when I tried to upload a file to the server. However, when I try to use main thread to upload or download, the program throws different error.

No starch, I will paste what I have done.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private TextView remoteContent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    String listUrl = "http://192.168.43.157:8080/apk/list.txt";
    remoteContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web_response);
    //String response = getWebResponse(listUrl);
    //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web_response);
    //textView.setText(response);

    GetApksListTask task = new GetApksListTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{listUrl});
}


private class GetApksListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); 
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            } 
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        remoteContent.setText(response);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is    present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```